# Error Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function query() on resource - PHP y SQL SERVER

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, php8

tengo un sistema el cual he desarrollado en PHP y MYSQL, he realizado la migración hacia SQL SERVER, instalando todo y he logrado realizar la conexión de PHP y SQL SERVER utilizando XAMMP, hasta ahí todo bien

cuando intento ingresar a mi sistema con mis credenciales me aparece el siguiente error

```
adminadmin
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function query() on resource in C:\xampp\htdocs\sistema_sondeo\validacion.php:14 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\sistema_sondeo\validacion.php on line 14
```

este es el código de mi archivo **conexion.php**

```
<?php

$serverName = "DESKTOP-SIMP7PV"; //serverName\instanceName
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"sistema_encuestasv1", "UID"=>"sa", "PWD"=>"123456789");
$con = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);

?>
```

y este mi archivo **validacion.php**

```
<?php   

session_start();

$id_usuario = $_POST['id_usuario'];
echo $id_usuario;
$clave  = $_POST['clave'];
echo $clave;
include("conexion.php");

$query = "SELECT * FROM sistema_encuestasv1.usuarios WHERE sistema_encuestasv1.id_usuario = '$id_usuario' AND clave = '$clave'";
    

    $resultado = $con->query($query);

    
    if ($row = $resultado->fetch_assoc()) {


        if ($row['id_tipo_usuario'] == '1') {
            $_SESSION['id_usuario'] = $row['id_usuario'];
            $_SESSION['u_usuario'] = $row['nombres'];
            header("Location: administrador/index.php");
        } else {
            $_SESSION['id_usuario'] = $row['id_usuario'];
            $_SESSION['u_usuario'] = $row['nombres'];
            header("Location: usuario/index.php");
        }
        
        if ($row['id_tipo_usuario'] == '3') {
            $_SESSION['id_usuario'] = $row['id_usuario'];
            $_SESSION['u_usuario'] = $row['nombres'];
            header("Location: usuario_vista/index.php");
        }

    } else {
        header("Location: index.php");
    }

    if (!$query) {
        printf("Error: %s\n", mysqli_error($conn));
        exit();
    }
    

 ?>
```

La conexión funciona perfecto, y este mismo código funcionaba bien en MYSQL, cabe resaltar que al momento de la migración, las tablas de mi BD quedaron de esta forma

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Que podrá estar pasando, o cual seria la razón del error

Comment: Se me hace que no has revisado la documentación para extención `SQLSRV`. Es más, estas utilizando sintaxis y funciones de `MySQLi`. Te recomiendo revisar [`Driver de Microsoft SQL Server`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/book.sqlsrv.php)

Comment: He revisado sin embargo no consigo realizar el login, mil disculpas es la primera vez que hago esto de migrar a SQL

Comment: Tenes que usar la función [sqlsrv_query](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.sqlsrv-query.php), fijate que la sintaxis es totalmente distinta.

Comment: He encontrado la solución, en un momento publicare la respuesta

Answer (score 0):

He encontrado la solucion por si a alguien le sirve

```
<?php   

session_start();

$id_usuario = $_POST['id_usuario'];
echo $id_usuario;
$clave  = $_POST['clave'];
echo $clave;
include("conexion.php");

$query = "SELECT * FROM sistema_encuestasv1.usuarios WHERE id_usuario = '$id_usuario' AND clave = '$clave'";
    
    $resultado = sqlsrv_query($con, $query);
    
    
    if ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($resultado)) {


        if ($row['id_tipo_usuario'] == '1') {
            $_SESSION['id_usuario'] = $row['id_usuario'];
            $_SESSION['u_usuario'] = $row['nombres'];
            header("Location: administrador/index.php");
        } else {
            $_SESSION['id_usuario'] = $row['id_usuario'];
            $_SESSION['u_usuario'] = $row['nombres'];
            header("Location: usuario/index.php");
        }
        
        if ($row['id_tipo_usuario'] == '3') {
            $_SESSION['id_usuario'] = $row['id_usuario'];
            $_SESSION['u_usuario'] = $row['nombres'];
            header("Location: usuario_vista/index.php");
        }

    } else {
        header("Location: index.php");
    }

    if (!$query) {
        printf("Error: %s\n", mysqli_error($con));
        exit();
    }





    
    

 ?>
```

Comment: Te falta corregir el manejo de errores. Se puede ver que todavía esas `mysqli_error`.